# MS Access : Records "added" to table, but not "in" table?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

In the process of building a Database for my employer.
This has been going mostly smoothly, but I have had an issue where a table "updates" but no record is inserted.

... well sort of not inserted.

I can't actually tell if it is or not. I mean it's not on the table, and my SQL query returns a 0 BUT my VBA SQL query returns a 1 on a record I told it to insert.

Code below

```
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim wrk As DAO.Workspace
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rsp As Integer
Dim uTable As String
Dim inSQL As String

Debug.Print pCurrentCmd

If pCurrentCmd = "NewIT" Then
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_IT_Staff " & _
        "WHERE GivenName LIKE " & Chr(34) & Chr(42) & _
        Me.txt_GivenName & Chr(42) & Chr(34) & _
        " AND Surname LIKE " & Chr(34) & Chr(42) & _
        Me.txt_Surname & Chr(42) & Chr(34) & ";")
    If rst.Fields(0) > 0 Then
        rsp = MsgBox("This person is already in the database!" & _
          vbCrLf & "Do you wish to proceed anyway? ", vbYesNo)
    Else
        Set rst = Nothing
        GoTo Finalize
    End If
    If rsp = 6 Then GoTo Finalize
    If rsp = 7 Then GoTo exitSub
    Set rst = Nothing
    
End If

Finalize:

Set wrk = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set db = wrk.OpenDatabase(CurrentDb.Name)
 
DoEvents

With wrk
    On Error GoTo ErrRollback
    
    If pCurrentCmd = "NewIT" Then
        uTable = "tbl_IT_Staff"
    End If
    
    
    .BeginTrans
    If IsNull(Me.txt_AOR) Then
        inSQL = "INSERT INTO " & uTable & " (GivenName, Surname) VALUES (" & _
            Chr(34) & Me.txt_GivenName & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & _
            Me.txt_Surname & Chr(34) & ");"
    Else
        inSQL = "INSERT INTO " & Chr(34) & uTable & Chr(34) & _
            " (GivenName, Surname) VALUES (" & Chr(34) & Me.txt_GivenName & _
            Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Me.txt_Surname & Chr(34) & _
            Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Me.txt_AOR & Chr(34) & ");"
    End If
    Debug.Print inSQL
    
    CurrentDb.Execute inSQL, dbFailOnError
    
    Call AuditLogR(DMax("ID", "tbl_IT_Staff"), "NewP", uTable)
    .CommitTrans

End With

exitSub:
    Exit Sub
```

Now I created a new test record : Test Tests and ran the code, it went through, and committed the transaction, BUT, no record exists in the table.

Ok, nbd, I made a change (had commented out the auditlog call, so put it back in) then decided to rerun the code, and see if the audit log updates or not (this has been a constant issue in every new instance of running the audit log, it "updates" but adds no record to the table.) This is the first case where a different table is claiming to have updated, but clearly has not. Often with the Auditlog it has been easily solved.

But what's throwing me off is the fact that this record both exists, and doesn't exist. and that using the same exact SQL query, I get different results depending on if it is done via VBA (where it is 'failing?') and SQL which matches the visible records on the table.

Anyone have any suggestions? Or a direction they can point me in?

Comment: 3 values, 2 fields in the second INSERT?

Comment: I do hope the entries are properly sanitized before being used...

Comment: It makes no difference whether you write `"WHERE GivenName LIKE " & Chr(34) & Chr(42)` or `"WHERE GivenName LIKE ""*"`. But in SQL you can use single quotes: `"WHERE GivenName LIKE '*"`. But make sure to replace one single (or double) quote by two in case they occur in the names: `"WHERE GivenName LIKE '*" & Replace(Nz(Me.txt_GivenName),"'","''") & "*'"`

Comment: Are you sure you are not running into the `On Error GoTo ErrRollback`?  If the commit fails, you get the wrong impression that it succeeded because the audit log is written before the commit. You should write to the audit log after `.CommitTrans` and also write to the audit in case of rollback to be informed about a failure.

Comment: Why would you use LIKE if you want to know if an exact name is already in db? Stephanie Smithson is not Stephan Smith but your code could match these. `"Stephanie" LIKE "*Stephan*"` will return True.

Comment: @June7 Due to the possibility of similar name being entered incorrectly. That's why it allows registration even if it returns "True". (I am actually going to clean up that msgbox later on, but for right now I am just getting basic functionality in place.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, I find that doing it via escape characters, doesn't require the substitution, in the event of a " ' " character being in place. It reads it in as a string, and then simply includes that character. I could be wrong, probably am, but this way feels cleaner, and more functional. 

It isn't going to the rollback, there's an exit sub on completion and I actually went step by step with it just to check. No idea, and after restarting the database, now it doesn't do that anymore, but it did increment the ID field the right number of times This one has me puzzled.

Comment: Using the `Chr()` function instead of string literals doesn't change anything to the escaping problem. The resulting SQL string is the same. Either you use the `"` as string delimiter in SQL or the `'`, but in both cases you must replace a single one by two of them to do the escape (`Replace(Me.txt_GivenName, """", """""")` or `Replace(Me.txt_GivenName, "'", "''")`). I have a helper function for this: `Public Function SqlStr(ByVal s As String) As String
    If s = "" Then
        SqlStr = "NULL"
    Else
        SqlStr = "'" & Replace(s, "'", "''") & "'"
    End If
End Function`